# How to use ticket kerberos in app electron.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing a cross platform application with electron.js. I need to call a web api that is on an iis server with integrated security.

On a Mac computer I created a kerberos ticket to connect to the web API, from a chrome browser it does not ask me for credentials because it uses the ticket ones. But from the app electron does not use the kerberos ticket. How I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use kerberos Node.js module in browser side of your application like this one, [kerberos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos) or you can search npm try different ones.
Later you can connect **browser side responsible for business logic** with **renderer side(UI)** via **ipc module**.